# Power series convergence at specific x values

Tags: power-series

for the series of $\sum C_n(x-2)^n$. We know that it converges when $x=4$ and diverges when $x=6$. lets say when $x=7, 5$ or $0.5$, how do we know if the series converges or not then?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum c_n(x-2)^n$?

Comment: yes, i dont know how to format on this website sorry

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A power series $\sum c_n(x-a)^n$ always has a radius of convergence $r\geq0$ so that the series converges when $|x-a|<r$ and diverges when $|x-a|>r.$  It may converge or diverge at the points where $|x-a|=r$, and it may converge at one of them and diverge at the other.

In this case, we have have $a=2$.  We are told that the series converges at $x=4$ so we know $r\geq2$.  We are told that it diverges when $x=6$ so we know $r\leq4$.  Then the series certainly converges at $x=.5$ and diverges at $x=7$, but we don't know what happens at $x=5$.  That will depend on the actual values of the $c_n$.